# Why trace_call (stateDiff) not show balance changes from internal txs?

Tags: transactions, internal-transactions, trace, erigon

I am using trace_call with stateDiff Tracer, to show balances changes after a transaction. Already tried to use [Erigon](https://github.com/ledgerwatch/erigon) and [core-geth](https://github.com/etclabscore/core-geth), the results are identical thoughout changes in usage.

For instance, this tx:
https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xffa922bc144466247cf1d94db849ae80d36c9d75b300636d6dc68d7ef6c6c114
generate this trace:

```
[
  {
    "statediff": {
      "0xd44fbeb26c88f0f18f72664e3c446e0c2836908d": {
        "balance": "=",
        "nonce": {
          "*": {
            "from": "0x209",
            "to": "0x20a"
          }
        },
        "code": "=",
        "storage": {}
      }
    }
  }
]
```

there is no changes in balances, but yes there was, as one can see in etherscan "state" flap. I've noted that this happens always in internal txs, and when there are no internals, the result is expected. Someone can explain why internal tx are not captured by trace? And more important, how to trace Internal Txs and show balance changes?

Comment: this state change is the increment of nonce on the Sender's account, on every transaction Ethereum increments your nonce, that's standard behavior

Comment: the transaction you link in Etherscan shows all the traces perfectly. you probably should put all the steps you are doing, then what is expected, and what is happening in reality so we can undersand you

Comment: note: balances of tokens is not the same as balances in ETH. the balance in ETH is stored in Ethereum merkle trie, the balance of the token is stored in the storage slot that belongs to the storage trie of the contract

Comment: The expected is the "state" from etherscan, i am getting the trace above (are the same transaction). The storage changes from internal txs are missing in the trace.

Comment: I am using [trace_callMany](https://etclabscore.github.io/core-geth/JSON-RPC-API/modules/trace/), can't post the code here

Comment: I don't know what `trace_callMany` is, I am using official `geth`. But what most likely is happening is that the state changes aren't captured because you don't have the `Debug` flag set

Comment: this is the flag (member name `Debug`) you need to set: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/d0a4989a8def7e6bad182d1513e8d4a093c1672d/core/vm/interpreter.go#L28

Comment: and this is the `if` condition that prevents state changes by internal transactions to appear https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/d0a4989a8def7e6bad182d1513e8d4a093c1672d/core/vm/interpreter.go#L163

Comment: so you need to check with the developer of `trace_callMany` why they aren't setting `Debug` to true

Comment: core-get accept as parameter an object with configuration, i am passing `"Debug": true`. Possibly the same thing.

Comment: well if you have Debug flag set then the state changes must be captured by the tracer. use `debug.traceTransaction()` then and it will work

Comment: it capures the state just before executing the instruction: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/d0a4989a8def7e6bad182d1513e8d4a093c1672d/core/vm/interpreter.go#L232

Comment: all SSTOREs are logged, so no way to miss anything: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/d0a4989a8def7e6bad182d1513e8d4a093c1672d/eth/tracers/native/prestate.go#L135

Answer (score 2):

Hi Developer advocate from [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) here

I can't tell if the full trace is working but

```
[
  {
    "statediff": {
      "0xd44fbeb26c88f0f18f72664e3c446e0c2836908d": {
        "balance": "=",
        "nonce": {
          "*": {
            "from": "0x209",
            "to": "0x20a"
          }
        },
        "code": "=",
        "storage": {}
      }
    }
  }
]
```

is perfectly correct.

This is a transaction swapping 0.07 WETH for ApeIn, during the tx, the sender `0xd44fbeb26c88f0f18f72664e3c446e0c2836908d` doesn't really lose any Eth except for his gas fee, which won't reflect in a trace_call.

A trace_call basically "simulates" a call against a specific "state", the gas fee is undetermined until the tx is finalized in a block. Hence it is not part of this "simulation". If you trace it using `trace_transaction`, you will probably see the balance reduce due to gas.

Your confusion comes from Etherscan incorrectly using the word "state" here. Maybe it has a different understanding from Geth, but here it certainly mixes Eth(the native currency) and WETH(wrapped Eth, a token) together.

`traceCall` with `stateDiff` doesn't trace smart contract data changes, as Nulik pointed out, that should be a storage change. You can use `debug_traceCall` with `disableStorage:false` to trace this changes.

I had two blog posts: [this](https://chainstack.com/deep-dive-into-eth_call/) is about eth_call, [this](https://chainstack.com/deep-dive-into-ethereum-trace-apis/) is about debug_trace API.
There are some examples that may help you.

Hope you find it useful, Happy coding!

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/v4hM08LU) is a trace_call complete, with changes in storage. From this [tx](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x1d703231b53238585be8f6f9626ef48d14435475f9690cb1906b36e8d45dfe0e). trace_call shows changes in storage, but when the tx have internal txs it not showing anymore, like the example given in the question. debug_traceCall is equivalente to trace_call, except for the response squema ([source](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/138370/trying-to-understand-the-difference-between-trace-call-and-debug-tracecall-metho)).